# Deleting a specific element from JSON

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to clean up my json file with jq and remove all the elements that don't belong to the city of Bern. Here is the JSON example:

```
[
{
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 46.93629499999999,
        "lng": 7.503256800000001
      }
    },
    "name": "La Tana Del Lupo",
    "price_level": 1,
    "rating": 4.4,
    "types": [
      "restaurant",
      "point_of_interest",
      "food",
      "establishment"
    ],
    "user_ratings_total": 84,
    "vicinity": "Dorfstrasse 11, Muri bei Bern"
  },
  {
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 46.93406969999999,
        "lng": 7.503247199999999
      }
    },
    "name": "Rung Reuang",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "types": [
      "restaurant",
      "point_of_interest",
      "food",
      "establishment"
    ],
    "user_ratings_total": 131,
    "vicinity": "Worbstrasse 198, Muri bei Bern"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to remove all the entries with the city "Ostermundigen" in it. I've tried different things:

`jq 'map(del(.vicinity|contains(“Ostermundigen”)))’ Bern.json`

this expects some input from me:

````
(base) dcha3453463$ jq 'map(del(.vicinity|contains(“Ostermundigen”)))’ clean_json/Bern.json

(base) dcha3453463$ jq < clean_json/Bern.json 'del(.[]|select(.vicinity(has"Ostermundigen”)))’
>

(base) dcha3453463$ jq 'del(.[]|select(.vicinity=="Ostermundigen")' clean_json/Bern.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
del(.[]|select(.vicinity=="Ostermundigen")
jq: 1 compile error
>```

What am I doing wrong?
````

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. `“…”` should be `"…"`

Answer (score 1):

You need `select` to filter the right items. Without `select`, the filter would traverse to the criteria and delete just that.

Also, `map(del(…))` would leave `null` values behind. Rather delete from outside the array, and descend to the items using `.[]` from within `del`:

```bash
del(.[] | select(.vicinity|contains("Ostermundigen")))
```

Comment: same result...
```(base) dcha3453463$ cat clean_json/Bern.json | jq 'del(.[] | select(.vicinity|contains("Ostermundigen")))’

>```

the console is waiting for input

Comment: @milami Maybe your actual input is different from the sample provided here. This [works](https://jqplay.org/s/7DXXWzAeiW_r) as expected (changed `"Ostermundigen"` to `"Dorfstrasse"` to see an effect)

Comment: no, it's same. I also tried with Dorfstrasse, same result

Comment: ok the ticks were formatted wrong... the last tick is slanted, if you can see :) It works, thank you!